# allow request from the code of one website only

Tags: api, security

I am building a private API which provides some data, I have already set CORS to only allow requests from my website, and that works, but there is a problem: a user can make the request with the chrome console from my website to the API and that request will succeed since the API has no real way to tell if the request comes from the code i have written.
So my question is: is there any way to tell that? is there any way to prevent users from making that request from my website to call the API and bypass the CORS?

Comment: Instead of making the calls at the front, make your server send the requests at the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your request model so that requests to the API come from the web server itself, rather than from a users client.

That way you can add authentication to the API and only allow requests that come directly from your web server. Then web server can then display those results to your users.

CORS is not a method for checking/enforcing authentication or authorisation. It is purely an additional security control to protect against browser-based security vulnerabilities (XSS etc).

Comment: Welp, authorization has always been in my plans but i never figured out how to implement it because all the script files are public so I can't just put there a key so how should I do that? I use nginx btw

Comment: If you're going to implement authorisation, it needs to be from a server-side language. I.e., not JavaScript scripts. You need the server to do the authorisation checks as it cannot be modified by your end users. If you are using Nginx, you can find some common PHP libraries that can handle some basic authentication for you.

Comment: Got it. Is there any way to do this with something like an ExpressJS server?